# What issues would arise if I decide to move my local network to IPv6?

Tags: router, dns, ipv6

I am managing a small corporate network, and actively investigate the possibility of getting rid of IPv4 entirely, at least on the LAN level. I intend to disable IPv4 DHCP and connect to each machine using their IPv6 addresses.

All of my devices support IPv6. My ISP is currently running dual stack (IPv4 + IPv6). What issues would arise if I decide to move my local network to IPv6?

Here are my efforts so far:

1. If I change the WAN connection in my router from the default `IPv4 + IPv6` to `IPv4 only`, it works. But if I set it to `IPv6 only`, I cannot connect to the Internet. I don't know why yet.
2. By disabling IPv4 support from Windows Network Adapter Properties, web browsers start looking for AAAA DNS records. Most websites still use A record, and do not have AAAA record (I don't know why they don't). The web browser cannot fall back to IPv4 option, and the domain names cannot be resolved.

Is it practical to use IPv6 exclusively on LAN as of now?

Comment: I’m curious why you want to do this? IPv4 isn’t going anywhere anytime soon, if ever. It’s far easier to manage on an internal network. Some problems have arisen in the past from disabling IPv6 in regards to certain Microsoft software and it is not recommended, I’m sure there are numerous issues that will arise from trying to disable IPv4. Things simply depend on it.

Comment: @Appleoddity I have a habit of adopting new technologies, and don't mind the efforts doing that. Old things will find their way out sooner or later, then why not now? Unless there are too many compatibility issues that render it impractical. That's the point of this question. :)

Comment: I started to suspect this question belongs to `serverfault.com`. Is it against the rule if I repost it there?

Comment: yes, it could go on [sf]. Just delete and repost there. I think this question comes down to a lot of theory or hypothesis. It’s really impossible to say what you have on your network or what configuration you have that may be incompatible with what you are trying to do. So it’s likely to be closed. The way to find out is to try, like you said. Sounds like you already ran in to issues.

Answer (score 1):

> If I change the WAN connection in my router from the default IPv4 + IPv6 to IPv4 only, it works. But if I set it to IPv6 only, I cannot connect to the Internet.

It's possible this may be a technical issue on your side. Setting up IPv6 can be an undertaking. If you believe you have set everything up correctly, you can always try checking a site like [Test IPv6](https://test-ipv6.com/) or Google to see if you have IPv6 connectivity.

> Most websites still use A records and do not have AAAA records (I don't know why they don't).

Overall, I think you are probably overestimating the deployment of IPv6 with regards to consumers and website adoption.

Mobile networks tend to have the best support for IPv6 (likely because they are often upgrading/expanding infrastructure), but in the US no ISP (mobile or traditional) has 100% IPv6 deployment to customers. At best, it averages about 60-80% of an ISP's customer base (and can be much lower, more broadly speaking). An ISP technically being dual-stack means little if its customers can't use IPv6. Furthermore, even if it is available, there is little incentive for customers to adopt it themselves. Most people likely don't care about any advantages of IPv6 over IPv4. They just want their devices to work.

With this in mind (as well as any costs associated with transitioning from IPv4 to IPv6), this creates a knock-on effect where the people who own and maintain websites apparently see little advantage to deploying IPv6 and AAAA records. As of 2018, Google reported only encountering IPv6 on about 25% of the websites it crawled.

> Is it practical to use IPv6 exclusively on a LAN as of now?

If it's a purely internal LAN, sure. But if you need to access the majority of the internet, you need to have at least one device with IPv4 enabled.